# Initial topology for a topological ring

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups, topological-rings

Given a topological ring $R$ and an arbitrary (thus not necessarily surjective) epimorphism $q: R \to S$ of underlying rings is there a *finest* topology on $S$ such that 1) $S$ is a topological ring and 2) $q: R \to S$ is continuous?

Comment: Do you mean onto or epimorphism in the category sense?

Comment: Yes. Not necessarily surjective. I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: The set $\mathscr T$ of all topologies on $S$ making the ring operations and $q$ continuous is not empty as it contains $\{\emptyset,S\}$. Isn't the least upper bound (i.e., the initial topology on $S$ for the mappings $id:X\to (X,\tau)$ with $\tau\in\mathscr T$) the finest ring topology on $S$ making $q$ continuous?